# Send errorcode response for Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, dom-events

I am trying to write some PHP to send either a successful result or an error code in response to an Ajax request.

I have the following (incomplete) JavaScript:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.onload=function() {
    // …
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
    // …
};
xhr.send();
```

The plan is to get PHP to send either a usable response or to return an error which will be caught by `xhr.onerror`.

I know how to send a suitable response from PHP, but I have no idea how to send something from PHP which will trigger the `error` event to JavaScript.

What do I need to return in PHP to get this result?

**Note:** I know how to generate notional error responses in PHP and to handle them in JavaScript. This is specifically on triggering the `error` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"onerror" fires when there is a failure on the network level also a denied cross-domain request . You can write a logic in such a way that getting a certain response from server means error well thats what i do

Comment: So, if gets anything at all from the server, then `error` doesn’t fire?

Comment: @Manngo i guess no :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the ajax format to be inserted in java script :-

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/......", **// your localhost url where u want to go i.e. page name example display.php**
        method: "GET",    **// the data you want to show u are getting GET or POST**
        success: function(data) {
             **// write that CODE here what u want to do with ajax.**
        },
        error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);  **// write that code which you want to display as an error**
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but (a) that doesn’t answer the question, (b) I have already give a working sample in my question and (c) jQuery is overkill in this case.

Comment: write this inside   :$(document).ready(function(){
   // ajax... code
});

Comment: I have made graph from jquery using same method mine is working